# How to change the parameter of activated Route on button click

Tags: angular, angular-router

Basically, I have two component `TodosComponent` and `TodoDetailsComponent`. Clicking on an item in `TodosComponent` takes me to the `TodoDetailsComponent` where I grab the parameter and fetch the required data from the API. All is working great.

But I want to make a next button on my `TodoDetailsComponent` so that the id passed to the parameter changes and I get the desired result based on the parameter as subscribed to the activatedRoute params. I google(d) and stackoverflow(ed) a lot but unable to find an example which give me direction to carry on. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xu6btm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodo.details.component.ts) is the working demo of the issue. Let me know if required more information. Any information will be helpful that whether is it possible or not.

TodoDetails.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  template: `<p>Todo Details Component</p>
    <div>{{ todo | json }}</div>
    <button type="button" (click)="next()">Next</button>
  `
})

export class TodoDetailsComponent implements OnInit{
  todo;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private service: Service) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(params => this.getTodo(+params.get('id')))
    ).subscribe(todo => this.todo = todo);
  }

  getTodo(id) {
    return this.service.getTodo(id);
  }

  next() {
    // if i grab the id over here and increment 
    // by id++ the id increases but as can be seen 
    // parameter is still the same, so won't work
  }
```

Comment: your route will still remain the same if you change the value of `id`, you can try and navigate using `Router` to your desired `id`. Or you can call `getTodo()` in your `next()` with the desired `id`, but route will still remain the same.

Comment: That is what i want to change the parameter when I click on next button and can I have example as you said "navigate using Router to your desired id"

Comment: Navigate to the same component in you `next()` function by appending the id `this.route.navigate['routeName', this.id]` inject router in the constructor and add this code in your `next()` function

Comment: try this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-su5hta)

Comment: Thanks @SarthakAggarwal working. Add this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Suryan you sure you that's the best possible way say by incrementing id++ as things are in sequence(kindoff hardcoiding IMHO). having no control over the real data.

Comment: @supercool If you have something more robust then please let me know, but as for now this is what I think is good. Give the answer playground is yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route will still remain the same if you change the value of `id`, you can try and navigate using `Router` to your desired `id`.

You can take help of this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-su5hta)

Comment: Calling `getTodo()` in `next` won't do anything because I am not subscribing to the `getTodo()` in the function instead using the function inside `switchMap` for that I have to change the code a bit more. But your demo is working fine, So please change your answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 2):

Just try to navigate to the same component by just changing the id `prams`

```
export class TodoDetailsComponent implements OnInit{
  todo;
  id: number;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private service: Service, 
              private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(params => {
          this.id = +params.get('id')
          return this.getTodo(this.id)
      })
    ).subscribe(todo => this.todo = todo);
  }

  getTodo(id) {
    return this.service.getTodo(id);
  }

  next() {
    this.id += 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/todos',this.id]);
  }
```

Hope this will work thanks - Happy coding !!

Comment: This line `this.id += this.id;` increase the id 1 for the first time and 2 for the second time and so on instead it should be `this.id = this.id + 1` or `this.id += 1`. Change your answer so that I can upvote

Comment: Yep that was a mistake - updated the answer - sorry for the confusion